# SwiftUI date picker is cut in ios 14.0

Tags: ios, swiftui, datepicker

The month&year picker is not visible, the overall view is cut at the top, after rotating the screen or selecting a day the view is fully visible, it only happens ios 14.0

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var birthDate = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        DatePicker(selection: $birthDate, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date) {
            Text("Select a date")
        }
        .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
    }
}
```

[image]

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: If the issue is only on iOS 14, have you checked the compatibility of `GraphicalDatePickerStyle` and the changes between iOS 14/15?

Comment: this might be a preview issue only. did you run it in simulator? That works fine with me.

Comment: @ChrisR I run on iPhone xs max simulator

Comment: @AbhinavMathur on ios 15 it work fine, as well on the other ios 14 versions, just 14.0 causes troubles